# How to pass XML and Schema as parameter via SOAP request using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

I need to be able to "Add a quote" via a SOAP API, which requires an XML and Schema to be passed as a parameter in the request.

For other requests I am using PHP's SoapClient, but I am not sure how to format this request? To test things I have tried sending the request via Curl in PHP, and it works but want to know how to use SoapClient... Can anyone help me out here? Very much appreciated.

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values (i.e. length, string, schema, xml...)

Request:

```
POST /abc/Quote.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://example.com/AddQuote"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AddQuote xmlns="http://example.com">
      <connectId>string</connectId>
      <dsQuote>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</dsQuote>
    </AddQuote>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
   <AddQuoteResponse xmlns="http://example.com">
     <AddQuoteResult>string</AddQuoteResult>
     <dtMessage>xmlxml</dtMessage>
   </AddQuoteResponse>
 </soap:Body>
```

Here is the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://example.com">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com">
<s:element name="AddQuote">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="connectId" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dsQuote">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element ref="s:schema"/>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="AddQuoteResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AddQuoteResult" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dtMessage">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax"/>
<s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="AddQuoteSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AddQuote"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AddQuoteSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AddQuoteResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="QuoteSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="AddQuote">
<wsdl:input message="tns:AddQuoteSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:AddQuoteSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="QuoteSoap" type="tns:QuoteSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="AddQuote">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/AddQuote" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="QuoteSoap12" type="tns:QuoteSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="AddQuote">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://example.com/AddQuote" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Quote">
<wsdl:port name="QuoteSoap" binding="tns:QuoteSoap">
<soap:address location="http://myserver/abc/Quote.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="QuoteSoap12" binding="tns:QuoteSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://myserver/abc/Quote.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This is an example of what it should look like (copied from another application performing the same function):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mar="http://example.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <mar:AddQuote>
      <mar:connectId>71a0-0e82-4c14-5bcb58bf9701-wer4</mar:connectId>
      <mar:dsQuote>
        <xs:schema id="CustomerQuote" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
          <xs:element name="CustomerQuote" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="CustomerQuote">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="QuoteID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="QuoteStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CustomerID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Reference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="SalesEntity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="WarehouseEntity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="EnterDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="EnterTime" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ShipDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ExpiryDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Terms" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ExtendedEx" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="TaxTotal" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ExtendedInc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Currency" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="SalesRep" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="TaxNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="TaxClass" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ExchangeRate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="QuoteTransactionType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Category1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Category2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Category3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Category4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Category5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Category6" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Special1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Special2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="NumLines" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Completed" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="SiteCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Address1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Address2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="PostalCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DeliveryName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DeliveryAddress1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DeliveryAddress2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DeliveryCity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DeliveryState" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DeliveryPostalCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="DeliveryCountry" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="FreightType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="FreightAccount" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Carrier" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Shipping" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Contact" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Fax" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Territory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="PriceCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="IsOpen" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Expired" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Accepted" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CustomerQuoteLine">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="QuoteID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="LineNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="LineNumberReference" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="LineType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ProductID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Barcode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ProductCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ProductGroup" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="UnitCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="CustomerProductCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Quantity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="QuantityReserve" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="QuantityKit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="BasePrice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="PriceCurr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Discount" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="UnitPrice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="FixedPrice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="SpecialPrice" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="TaxIncluded" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="PricePer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Override" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ExtendedEx" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="TaxTotal" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ExtendedInc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="Comment" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ShipDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                      <xs:element name="ExpiryDate" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
          <CustomerQuote>
            <CustomerQuote diffgr:id="CustomerQuote1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
              <QuoteID>123456</QuoteID>
              <QuoteStatus>SUBMITTED</QuoteStatus>
              <CustomerID>555555</CustomerID>
              <Reference>123456</Reference>
              <SalesEntity>999</SalesEntity>
              <Currency>AUD</Currency>
              <NumLines>1</NumLines>
              <Contact>mrsmith@example.com</Contact>
              <Email>mrsmith@example.com</Email>
              <Phone/>
              <Comment>Some comment here</Comment>
            </CustomerQuote>
            <CustomerQuoteLine diffgr:id="CustomerQuoteLine1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
              <QuoteID>123456</QuoteID>
              <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
              <ProductID>3898</ProductID>
              <Description>BIG BROWN BOX</Description>
              <UnitCode>EA</UnitCode>
              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
              <Price>9.99</Price>
              <PriceCurr>9.99</PriceCurr>
            </CustomerQuoteLine>
          </CustomerQuote>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
      </mar:dsQuote>
    </mar:AddQuote>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What have you tried? You soap client would consume the WSDL then you would call the functions off your soap request object. http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Not quite sure why you think you need to send the schema, just the XML payload with the right namespaces is usually what you need.  Can you explain that?  Or do you mean the SOAP Action?  Show us what code you have so far and what issues you are having or errors you are getting.

Comment: The reason why I think I need to supply a schema is because I am getting an error: 

"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'schema' property"

I have all the data loaded into an array, I am not sure how to pass this as XML for the parameter. Any help appreciated :)

Here is an example:

[https://pastebin.com/m6VywZVm](https://pastebin.com/m6VywZVm)

Comment: I can get it working using Curl, but would like to know how to structure this using SoapClient